Is there a way to use Locomotive scroll with NextJS app router
I would like to know if there is a way to implement locomotive scrolling (or smooth scrollbar) with NextJS app router without deopting from SSR?

Create a wrapper component for the locomotive scroll and add it to your layout.tsx
"use client";

import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function LocoScroll({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const LocomotiveScroll = (await import("locomotive-scroll")).default;
      const scroll = new LocomotiveScroll();
    })();
  }, []);
  return <>{children}</>;
}

export default LocoScroll;

and in the layout file:
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <LocoScroll>
      <html>
        .....
      </html>
    </LocoScroll>
  );
}

